# Which of these two functions more "pythonic"?

Tags: python

I just want to know which way is more preferable in python.
Imagine two functions:

## 1 function:

```
def foo(key):
    if bar.has_key(key):
        return bar.get(key)
    # do something with bar
    # this will be executed if bar_key(key) is False
    ...
    return something
```

## 2 function:

```
def foo(key):
    if bar.has_key(key):
        return bar.get(key)
    else:
        # do something with bar
        # this will be executed if bar_key(key) is False
        ...
        return something
```

As you can see the only difference is `else` statement. So the question is will it affect performance somehow. Or are there any reasons to include `else` in this type of functions?

Comment: Assuming bar is a `dict`, how about `return bar.get(key,something)` ?

Comment: Rather opinion based and I don't think it's specific to Python or being "pythonic". From what I've heard the first option is more readable, and I also choose this version.

Comment: Neither is; use `if key in bar: return bar[key]`; no need to use `get()` and `has_key()`.

Comment: Thank you @Martijn Pieters I'll follow you suggestion as well

Comment: Also `try: return bar[key]` `except:...` is commonly used (helps avoid race conditions)

Comment: @Vor: You don't need the `else` either, as you already return in the `if` suite. The function ends there, so `else` is redundant really.

Comment: @gnibbler That doesn't really eliminate race conditions, it just makes the window smaller.  There is still a race condition in that code.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Should a function have only one return statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement). In this case, as Martijn mentioned, the `else` is not needed as you return in the `if` anyway, so the `else` will only unnecessarily increase the indentation level, making the code less readable. So between 1 and 2, 1 wins. But you should really use `key in bar` and `bar[key]` for a *pythonic* solution.

Comment: Hi @poke, can you tell more about this? why not?

Comment: @Vor: `dict.has_key()` is deprecated in favour of `key in dict`; once you've established that the key is in the dict, there is no need to use `.get()` anymore, just grab the value *directly* using `dict[key]`.

Comment: I actually prefer the `else` version; that way it's clear just from the outermost code structure that these are two mutually exclusive blocks, without having to read what's in the first block. Certainly if the first block had more complicated code inside it (with more control flow constructs) it's nicer to not have to mentally run termination analysis to find out whether the rest of the code should be read in the context of the condition being false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the choice is between those two approaches, I would pick the first one.  `return` is pretty explicit that execution terminates at that point.  I find `if x { return y } else { ... }` an anti-pattern for this reason (not just in Python -- I see this in C/C++ code and it irks me there, too).

If you are returning, an `else` block is entirely unnecessary and causes pointless indentation of a block of code that might be quite large.  The more nested structures you have, the more difficult it is to maintain proper context in your head while reading code.  For this reason I tend to prefer less nesting when it does not obfuscate logic, and in this case I don't think it would.

Comment: [Yes, a thousand times yes.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/18454/7043)

Answer (score 4):

The pythonic way:

```
def foo(key):
    return bar.get(key, something)
```

Comment: Depending on how long it takes to compute the value of `something`, yes.  If it takes a non-negligible amount of time, one would be pre-computing a value that is never used.

Comment: Well, what if I need to do some something let's say call the DB, to retrieve this key, and than update dict?

Comment: @Vor: If you want to update your dictionary with `something` anyway, you could also just check if `key not in bar` and compute `something` and then set `bar[key] = something` within the then block. Afterwards, just return `bar[key]`.

Answer (score 4):

While this question is a little opinion based, I'd say the second is more *Pythonic* for the reason of "explicit is better than implicit".  The second function is clearly saying "if this condition, do this.  Otherwise, do this".  On the other hand, the first function *implies* the "Otherwise" part.